# Conversion of tree to graph data structure in java

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert a graph data structure to a tree data structure in java?
If possible can some one provide me the source?

Comment: Isn't [a tree a special case of graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph))? Therefore, there is no need for conversion. Or have I misunderstood the question? In such case, please be so kind and provide more details.

Comment: @Sorrow...the basic need for this conversion is tree is having hierarchical structure where as graph doesn't..and my app only details with hierarchical structure...

Answer (score 4):

All trees are valid graphs. So this should work

```
Object ConvertTreeToGraph( TreeData t )
{
   return t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, just because a *tree* is a special *graph*. But as we have several datastructures to model trees and several datastructures for graphs it's not possible to give "one code to convert them all".

**Further Reading**

- [Tree Structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure)
- [Graph representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29#Representations)